# Database Design - Creating a table with only two values, or make it a column that has either of those two values

Tags: database-design

It is more of a database design question and am curious how professional database admins would approach when there are only two set of values - take an example below of two design scenario and which you would choose; and why?

**Scenario One**

```
 table INVOICES
 -------------------------------
 id | royalty_fee | royalty_type
 -------------------------------
 1  | 15          | percentage
 2  | 10.00       | fixed
 1  | 25          | percentage
 1  | 25.00       | fixed
```

or....

**Scenario Two**

```
 table INVOICES
 ----------------------------------
 id | royalty_fee | royalty_type_id
 ----------------------------------
 1  | 15          | 1
 2  | 10.00       | 2
 1  | 25          | 1
 1  | 25.00       | 2


 table ROYALTY_TYPES
 -------------------------------
 id | label
 -------------------------------
 1  | percentage
 2  | fixed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach 2 is better. Your developers can use the 2nd table ROYALTY_TYPES for lookup, also if you want to add a new type or edit/update the label of the ROYALTY_TYPES you can do it easily. 
If you edit/modify label in ROYALTY_TYPES it will require change in only one place and the table INVOICES will be unaffected

 EDIT:
I usually look for three things with respect to database design:
**How easy it is to Add:** In your first approach, you will not able to add new Royalty types if you don't happen to have a record for invoice. I mean if you want to add a new type lets say HalfFixed for future invoices. You will not be able to do it, without getting an invoice of of type HalfFixed
**How easy it is to update** Lets say if you want to update Royalty Type Fixed to 'FIX'. If you are following first approach then you would be required to update it in multiple rows. 

 **How  easy it is to delete** Now if you want to delete a type from Royalty Types then according to your first approach you will have to run an update statement on the table and setting the particular royalty type to NULL.

Comment: Agreed. Also, you get the benefit of foreign-key constraints to make sure that values inserted conform to the available set of values.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, @Habib.OSU.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the latter, no question about it.

1. Can you be absolutely sure there will NEVER be another royalty type? No, you cannot.
2. You can validate the royalty_type_id column by a foreign key relationship...not so with royalty_type...you'd have to use a check constraint with the text values hard-coded.
3. With the royalty_types table, you can add new features as needed to the royalty type entity itself.

Answer (score 1):

On transactional db, 2 is better. 1 is usable for datawarehouse systems.